# Display object from different table

Tags: django

I am using Django and Django-tables2. I have a model that looks like this:

```
# models.py
class Word(models.Model):
[...]
    word_category = models.ForeignKey('Wordcategory', db_column='word_category')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Word'

class Wordcategory(models.Model):
    [...]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'WordCategory'
```

In my table, I am displaying entries from the table Word, but I for every Word object I want to show the name value of the corresponding WordCategory object. How do I do that?

Edit: My table class now looks like this, no category is being printed, neither in the console or on the website:

```
class CategoryColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        return value.name


class WordsTable(tables.Table):
    category = CategoryColumn(verbose_name="Kategorie", accessor="category")

    def render_category(self, value):
        print value.name
        return value.name

    class Meta:
        model = Word
        attrs = {"class": "table"}
```

Comment: word_object.word_category.name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django-tables2, you can add a [render method](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html#table-render-foo-methods) to customize how a column is rendered.

```
class WordTable(tables.Table):
    def render_word_category(self, value):
        """Display the name of the category"""
        return value.name

    class Meta:
        model = Word
```

An alternative would be to change the `__str__` method (`__unicode__` in Python 2) to return the name. However this will affect other places where you display word categories, so you might not want to make this change.

```
class Wordcategory(models.Model):
    [...]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Did you get this answer work in the end? You don't have to accept the answer if it didn't solve your problem.